# Joining with additional tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

I have 5 tables, categories, custom_prices, employees, custom_price_employees and products

- categories: id, name, active
- custom_prices: id, category_id, product_id, price,
- custom_price_employees: id, category_id, employee_id
- products: id, name, price
- employees: id, name

The goal is to show different prices for each employee on one product.

The idea is to show a certain price by combining some products and some employees in the same category, and these products should show a noble price in other employees.

so far what i've tried hasn't worked

Comment: When you say `"so far what i've tried hasn't worked"` could you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get custom prices for employees on a specific product.

```
$productByEmployee = Product::leftJoin('custom_prices','custom_prices.product_id','=','products.id'
->leftJoin('categories','categories.id','=','custom_prices.category_id')
->leftJoin('custom_price_employees','custom_price_employees.category_id','=','categories.id')
->leftJoin('employees','employees.id','=','custom_price_employees.employee_id')
->select('products.name as product_name','products.price as noble_price','custom_prices.price as custom_price','category.name as category','employees.name as employee'
->where('products.id','=',2)
->get();
```

Same query can be reused or altered for various needs. You can play with the `where`